# Should i write "introduction to" or "introduction of"?

Tags: word-choice

I'm writing the Table of Contents for a document, but I'm confused to what I should use... Is it "introduction to the (sample) chisel" or "introduction of the chisel"?

Comment: Is the section/chapter introducing the chisel to the reader or discussing the introduction of the chisel to the world/technology/etc.?

Answer (score 2):

"Introduction of the chisel"
In prehistoric times, when was chisel first used? (When was the chisel introduced?)
OR
"introduction to the chisel"
The "chisel" is some topic to be discussed, and this is the introductory part of that discussion.